# Open link in anothoer tab vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to open a link in another tab like we always do with  `target="_blank"`

I'm doing this:

```html
<div v-if="webPage" class="practice-item__web-page">
   <a :href="webPage" target="_blank">
      {{ webPage }}
   </a>
</div>
```

But when the users clicks in the anchor tag they are not redirect, the anochor tag add the link to the url of the website like this
`https://partner-stage.smiledirectclub.com/www.elly.com`

Comment: Thy adding the protocol before the URL: `<a :href="'http://' + webPage" target="_blank">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this: -

```
<div v-if="webPage" class="practice-item__web-page">
   <a :href="'http://' + webPage" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer">
      {{ webPage }}
   </a>
</div>
```